# Jupyter notebook error for C++ Kernel[cling]

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, cling

I have installed cling kernel for using C++ in Jupiter notebook
but after implementing the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int a;
  a=9;
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
 }
```

I am getting an error as ---> error: function definition is not allowed here
int main() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cling you don't write the whole program code. It's like a script language. You just write the lines that should be evaluated. Don't write the `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
a=9;
cout<<a;
```

You can also define functions in cling but then you are not allowed to write other code into the same cell.

Comment: It Works well in C++ kernel 14,but getting an error in C++17. Thanks @Thomas

Comment: @AbtabM That's strange. It should also work in C++17 kernel. You can check the documentation https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling  and the online platform https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/jupyter-xeus-xeus-cling-9p0ammy1/notebooks/notebooks/xcpp.ipynb I'm not experienced with cling so I can't help any further.

Comment: Thanks A lot , i'll check the documentation too

Comment: I can define then call the function in same cell…