# error: function definition not allowed here - while running the following C++ code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook

This seems like a perfectly valid C++ code to me which compiles alright in VSCode but refuses to work in Jupyter notebook. Any pointers to get around this would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() { 
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
    std::cout << (1+3)[arr];
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << (1 + 3)[arr] - arr[0] + (arr + 1)[2];
    std::cout << "\n"; 
}
```

The error I get is the following

> input_line_23:3:12: error: function definition is not allowed here int
> main() {
> ^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook error for C++ Kernel\[cling\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751544/jupyter-notebook-error-for-c-kernelcling)

Comment: Thanks - it does; I didn't realise the cling angle.