# How is Xeus-cling interpreting C++? Practical, User explanation -forgotten defs and function defs not allowed

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook, xeus-cling

Running xeus-cling(v0.13.0) under jupyter notebooks allows to run C++ code in code cells, sometimes.. Note: this is an issue with Jupyter notebook implementation of cling, Xeus -running cling at the command line does not have these problems.

For examples, It seems to randomly remember certain definitions and forget others:

In cell 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

In cell 2:

```
cout << "D\n";
cout <<"D" << endl;
```

gives:

```
input_line_9:3:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'; did you mean 'std::endl'?
cout <<"D" << endl;
              ^~~~
              std::endl
/home/don/miniconda3/envs/xeus-cling/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/ostream:599:5: note: 'std::endl' declared here
    endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
```

Also, whether it will accept a function definition or not seems unpredictable to me.
Here is an example:

In cell 1:

```
#include <iostream>
```

cell 2:

```
using namespace std;
void f2(){
    cout << "HI\n";
}
```

gives:

```
input_line_8:3:10: error: function definition is not allowed here
void f2(){
         ^
Interpreter Error:
```

while, In cell 3:

```
using namespace std;
cout << "using std" << endl;
```

gives:

```
using std
```

then, in cells 4 & 5:

```
void f2(){
    cout << "HI, still using std.\n";
}
f2();
```

happily gives:

```
HI, still using std.
```

Is there some explanation out there for what xeus-cling is doing between cells?? how it's interpreting C++ (at a high, user level)?
I do not see anything discussing this here [readthedocs](https://xeus-cling.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [here](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling).

More clues:
In cell 1:

```
void a() {}
void b() {}
```

gives

```
error: function definition is not allowed here
 void b() {}
```

and seems can define at most one function per cell is an *implicit rule* of xeus-cling. Can we make these rules explicit?

Another bug:

```
struct A {
  A(int);
  int i;
};
A::A(int x) : i{x} {}
```

gives:

```
error: expected '{' or ','
A::A(int x) : i{x} void __cling_Un1Qu31(void* vpClingValue) {
```

but

```
A::A(int x) { i = x; }
```

is accepted. It's actually cling that can't accept class member initializer lists and xeus-cling inherits the bug.

But wrapping the above struct def followed by ctor def in a namespace results in no bug:

```
namespace aa {
  struct A {
    A(int);
    int i;
  };
}
namespace aa {
  A::A(int x) : i{x} {}
}
aa::A a{3};
a.i
```

prints out `3` in cling, and gives:

```
input_line_8:5:2: error: unknown type name 'a'
 a.i;
```

in xeus-cling, unless `a.i` is moved to a new cell where it will give `3`.

Comment: "v0.13.0" <---- the "0" right after the "v" normally means "this is not a mature version, expect bugs, inconsistencies and random weirdness".

Comment: It looks pretty consistent to me: don't put 2 declarations in the same cell... Possibly the parser looks for a single declaration, and falls back to assuming this is a list of statements (that in normal C++ would need to be inside a function).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. v0.13.0 is the most recent version listed at https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling and is what conda is using. What you point out may also explain things..

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?
C++14 or C++17 or C++11?

Comment: @Abdulahad C++14. I had problems running the C++17 kernel. (common problem via google search)

Comment: @MarcGlisse But try ```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int i;
int j;
i = 3;``` in one cell, then ```cout << i;``` prints 3 in next cell, cout <<j; in next is all good. So it is getting and remembering declarations of i and j. etc...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is how the xeus-cling works like the explanation is given in this link:

[Jupyter notebook error for C++ Kernel[cling]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751544/jupyter-notebook-error-for-c-kernelcling)

Some rules are given in this link:
https://code-ballads.net/generated-notebooks/cpp/repl_cling/notebooks/3_Advices_And_Gotchas.html

> if cling repeatedly fails to compile/evaluate a cell (Function
> definition not allowed here, or various type errors), the kernel may
> have gotten corrupted / in a bad state, so just use Kernel -> Restart
> And Run All Cells. Actually the xeus-cling works as a interpreter
> that's why it reads only one instruction in a single cell and doesn't
> act like compiler.

Details are provided in this link:
https://blog.jupyter.org/interactive-workflows-for-c-with-jupyter-fe9b54227d92

[image]

The difference between compiler and interpreter is given in this link:
[https://www.businessinsider.in/difference-between-compiler-and-interpreter/articleshow/69523408.cms#:~:text=Compliers%20and%20interpreters%20are%20programs,be%20understood%20by%20the%20computers.&text=Compiler%20scans%20the%20entire%20program,to%20analyze%20the%20source%20code](https://www.businessinsider.in/difference-between-compiler-and-interpreter/articleshow/69523408.cms#:%7E:text=Compliers%20and%20interpreters%20are%20programs,be%20understood%20by%20the%20computers.&text=Compiler%20scans%20the%20entire%20program,to%20analyze%20the%20source%20code).
[image]

Comment: xeus-cling can often handle more than one statement per cell...

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the 'reboot' when kernel gets corrupted. It makes sense that, e.g., u can't redefine the same name multiple times (as in re-running same cell with a definition). And that the kernel itself is already 'running main()' so you don't want to define a 'main()' function. The second link you provided is a useful start to what's needed, but it should focus on the differences with C++ -we know we can't redefine things etc. But, Yes, a compendium of 'gotchas' and eventually a coherent understanding thereof. I'm managing to create C++ Jupyter notebooks and love it! (most of time)